# Simulate Fire & Forget scenario using C# Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, isoneway

I have a web service, which takes lot of time to execute. I am planning to delegate the processing task to a background thread & return the acknowledgement response to the user immediately.

In this case I was worried about the life-time of the background thread.
Will background thread complete the delegated task, before main method/thread finishes execution?

Comment: "web service method must have returned the value" , which value? the value from your background thread? You said ur background thread will run a BIG task, why you want to wait for its finishing?

Comment: Or alternatively, just implement an asynchronous call, which is more simple IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your service asynchronously.

```
var service = new YouServiceClient();
service.SomeMethodCompleted +=
  (sender, args) +=
  {
    //  Put code here to handle the response and extract a return value or whatever.
  }
service.SomeMethodAsync();
```

Refer to [How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your background thread might get aborted if the app pool gets recycled. Have a look at this article [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in Web Service for “Fire and Forget” task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300308/threadpool-queueuserworkitem-in-web-service-for-fire-and-forget-task?rq=1)